# Google Drive REST API update content as HTML with Landscape Orientation google-drive-sdk

Tags: api, rest, google-api, google-drive-api, httprequest

I've developed a service to update the content of a google document from salesforce. Using the google drive rest API. https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/

These are the steps I follow:

1. Get the Id of a shared document. (I called this the template)
2. Clone (copy) the document on Drive.
3. Get the content of that document in HTML form and save it in a string variable.
4. Replace some words on that string variable.
5. Update the new content on the new copied document.

It works great! BUT My problem is that IF the template (step 1) have a orientation landscape, when I update the document with the new content (step 5) the orientation changes to Portrait.

These are the request I do for it:

- To COPY the file:

POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/FILEID/copy

```
public String post(String url, String jsonStr) {
    HttpRequest req = createRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(url);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    req.setBody(jsonStr);
    HttpResponse res = sendRequest(req);
    if (isOK(res)) {
        return res.getBody();
    }
    throw buildResponseException(res);
}
```

- To Get the HTML Content:

After copy the file it returns the parameters of the new created file, including "exportLinks". So I get the "text/html" export link. And do a GET to that URL.

- To Update the Content:

PUT https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/FILEID?uploadType=media

```
public String put(String url, Blob jsonStr) {
     HttpRequest req = createRequest();
     req.setEndpoint(url);
     req.setMethod('PUT');
     req.setHeader(HTTP_HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, 'text/html');
     req.setHeader(HTTP_HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH, String.valueOf(jsonStr.size()));
     req.setBodyAsBlob(jsonStr);
     HttpResponse res = sendRequest(req);
     if (isOK(res)) {
         return res.getBody();
     }
     throw buildResponseException(res); }
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is after update the content but I haven't found why. Also, I used v3 of the API and is the same behavior.

Comment: I am not seeing the issue that you explained here. I'm just curious what browser or app are you using to view the content? was this with Chrome? It may also help if you provide some screenshot of the issue.

Comment: The problem is this: The template is Landscape and the new copy (when is updated) result as Portrait, I want that to keep Landscape as the template.